# Loan C# console app, interest total doesn't start at zero

Tags: c#, methods, calculation

I've got this working the way it should, except the output for the first row shows the running total for interest payment as already summarized, instead the same as the first interest amount. So if the first month is 1.05 interest, running total for first month should show 1.05. Second month would be 1.05 + new interest amount. Right now it shows for example above, 2.10 as first month total.
Where is my logic screwed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Loan_Program
{
    class Loan
    {
        //declare variables
        private double LoanAmount, InterestRate;
        private int LoanLength;

        //Constructor of Loan class that takes amount, rate and years
        public Loan(double amount, double rate, int years)
        {
            this.LoanAmount = amount;
            this.InterestRate = (rate / 100.0) / 12.0;
            this.LoanLength = years;
        }
        //returns the monnthly payment
        public double GetMonthlyPayment()
        {
            int months = LoanLength * 12;
            return (LoanAmount * InterestRate * Math.Pow(1 + InterestRate, months)) / (Math.Pow(1 + InterestRate, months) - 1);
        }
        //Calculates totl interterest paid and doubles it, then returns the amount
        public double TotalInterestPaid(double number1,double number2)
        {
            double TotalInterest = number1+number2;

            return  TotalInterest;
        }


        //prints the amortization of Loan
        public void LoanTable()
        {
            double monthlyPayment = GetMonthlyPayment();//calculates monthly payment
            double principalPaid = 0;
            double newBalance = 0;
            double interestPaid = 0;
            double principal = LoanAmount;
            double totalinterest = 0;
            //nonth, payment amount, principal paid, interest paid, total interest paid, balance
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}{4,10}{5,10}", "Payment Number", "Payment Amt", "Interest Paid", "Principal paid","Balance Due","Total Interest Paid");
            for (int month = 1; month <= LoanLength * 12; month++)
            {
                // Compute amount paid and new balance for each payment period
                interestPaid = principal * InterestRate;
                principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;
                newBalance = principal - principalPaid;
                totalinterest += interestPaid;
                // Output the data item              
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,10:N2}{2,10:N2}{3,10:N2}{4,10:N2}{5,10:N2}",
 month, monthlyPayment, interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance, TotalInterestPaid(totalinterest,interestPaid));
                // Update the balance
                principal = newBalance;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Main Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Loan_Program
{
    class LoanTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declare variables
            double amount;
            double rate;
            int years;
            //prompt loan amount
            Console.WriteLine("Enter loan amount");
            amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable
            //prompt for rate
            Console.WriteLine("Enter annual interest rate");
            rate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable
            //prompt for monhts
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number of years");
            years = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable

            Loan loan = new Loan(amount, rate, years);//create  new instance, send values to the class

            loan.LoanTable();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Use Breakpoints in the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints) and [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: Just move the line _interestPaid = principal * InterestRate;_ at the end of the loop?

Comment: Don't use `double` for monetary calculations. `decimal` is for money. `double` is for scientific values. `decimal` doesn't suffer rounding issues to the same extent as `double`.

Comment: You actually have a lot of bad ideas here. You can't do `this.InterestRate = (rate / 100.0) / 12.0;` - that's not the correct calculation. If you have an annual interest rate then to calculate the monthly rate you need to do `this.InterestRate = Math.Pow(1.0 + rate / 100.0, 1.0 / 12.0) - 1.0;`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I made that change. It makes more sense now. I tried changing to decimal but get so many errors and the can't use '/' error.

Comment: @jlarm - I popped in an answer showing how to use `decimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the `totalinterest` before the new `interestPaid` is calculated.

```
    //prints the amortization of Loan
    public void LoanTable()
    {
        double monthlyPayment = GetMonthlyPayment();//calculates monthly payment
        double principalPaid = 0;
        double newBalance = 0;
        double interestPaid = 0;
        double principal = LoanAmount;
        double totalinterest = 0;
        //nonth, payment amount, principal paid, interest paid, total interest paid, balance
        Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}{4,10}{5,10}", "Payment Number", "Payment Amt", "Interest Paid", "Principal paid", "Balance Due", "Total Interest Paid");
        for (int month = 1; month <= LoanLength * 12; month++)
        {
            // Compute amount paid and new balance for each payment period
            totalinterest += interestPaid;
            interestPaid = principal * InterestRate;
            principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;
            newBalance = principal - principalPaid;
            // Output the data item              
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,10:N2}{2,10:N2}{3,10:N2}{4,10:N2}{5,10:N2}",
                month, monthlyPayment, interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance, TotalInterestPaid(totalinterest, interestPaid));
            // Update the balance
            principal = newBalance;
        }
    }
```

Is this correct now?

```
Enter loan amount
100
Enter annual interest rate
10
Enter number of years
1
Payment NumberPayment AmtInterest PaidPrincipal paidBalance DueTotal Interest Paid
1               8.79      0.83      7.96     92.04      0.83
2               8.79      0.77      8.02     84.02      1.60
3               8.79      0.70      8.09     75.93      2.30
4               8.79      0.63      8.16     67.77      2.93
5               8.79      0.56      8.23     59.54      3.50
6               8.79      0.50      8.30     51.24      3.99
7               8.79      0.43      8.36     42.88      4.42
8               8.79      0.36      8.43     34.45      4.78
9               8.79      0.29      8.50     25.94      5.07
10              8.79      0.22      8.58     17.37      5.28
11              8.79      0.14      8.65      8.72      5.43
12              8.79      0.07      8.72      0.00      5.50
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help with the use of `decimal` rather than `double` here's the code you need:

```
void Main()
{
    //declare variables
    decimal amount;
    decimal rate;
    int years;
    //prompt loan amount
    Console.WriteLine("Enter loan amount");
    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable
                                                   //prompt for rate
    Console.WriteLine("Enter annual interest rate");
    rate = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable
                                                 //prompt for monhts
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number of years");
    years = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//accepts console input and assigne to variable

    Loan loan = new Loan(amount, rate, years);//create  new instance, send values to the class

    loan.LoanTable();
}

class Loan
{
    //declare variables
    private decimal LoanAmount, InterestRate;
    private int LoanLength;

    //Constructor of Loan class that takes amount, rate and years
    public Loan(decimal amount, decimal rate, int years)
    {
        this.LoanAmount = amount;
        this.InterestRate = DecPow(1m + rate / 100m, 1m / 12m) - 1m;
        this.InterestRate.Dump();
        this.LoanLength = years;
    }
    //returns the monnthly payment
    public decimal GetMonthlyPayment()
    {
        int months = LoanLength * 12;
        return (LoanAmount * InterestRate * DecPow(1m + InterestRate, months)) / (DecPow(1m + InterestRate, months) - 1m);
    }
    //Calculates totl interterest paid and doubles it, then returns the amount
    public decimal TotalInterestPaid(decimal number1, decimal number2)
    {
        decimal TotalInterest = number1 + number2;

        return TotalInterest;
    }

    //prints the amortization of Loan
    public void LoanTable()
    {
        decimal monthlyPayment = GetMonthlyPayment();//calculates monthly payment
        decimal principalPaid = 0m;
        decimal newBalance = 0m;
        decimal interestPaid = 0m;
        decimal principal = LoanAmount;
        decimal totalinterest = 0m;
        //nonth, payment amount, principal paid, interest paid, total interest paid, balance
        Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}{4,10}{5,10}", "Payment Number", "Payment Amt", "Interest Paid", "Principal paid", "Balance Due", "Total Interest Paid");
        for (int month = 1; month <= LoanLength * 12; month++)
        {
            // Compute amount paid and new balance for each payment period
            totalinterest += interestPaid;
            interestPaid = principal * InterestRate;
            principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;
            newBalance = principal - principalPaid;
            // Output the data item              
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}{1,10:N2}{2,10:N2}{3,10:N2}{4,10:N2}{5,10:N2}",
                month, monthlyPayment, interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance, TotalInterestPaid(totalinterest, interestPaid));
            // Update the balance
            principal = newBalance;
        }
    }

    private decimal DecPow(decimal x, decimal y) => (decimal)System.Math.Pow((double)x, (double)y);
    private decimal DecPow(decimal x, int p)
    {
        if (p == 0) return 1m;
        decimal power = 1m;
        int q = Math.Abs(p);
        for (int i = 1; i <= q; i++) power *= x;
        if (p == q)
            return power;
        return 1m / power;
    }
}
```

Take special note of the `DecPow` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float Amount, Year;
        float Rate;
        double total = 0;
        Console.Write("Enter Amount Per Year:");
        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Rate :");
        Rate = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter Time :");
        Year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 1; i <= Year; i++)
        {
            var current = Amount * (Rate / 100) * i;
            total += current;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Simple Interest is :{0}", total);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

> `The using another method i can find Total Interest`

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: if we want calculate the Interest for 1,00,000 than having rate 2.5 and time 15 year than we want to add year wise Interest  into total Interest than we get correct answer..